# What exactly is Dr Strange scared of?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, language-explanation, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr Strange-616 says to Christine-838:

> Dr Strange-616: I love you in every universe. It's not that I don't wanna care for someone or have someone care for me. It's just...**I get scared**.

Here Dr Strange-616 is saying that he is afraid of something, which is preventing him from caring for someone or having someone care for him.

What exactly is Dr Strange scared of?

Comment: Simple, he is afraid of losing that person. You can't lose anyone if you don't have anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange is likely alluding to the prospect of having his heart broken, which is a risk that comes with falling in love with someone, since you may ultimately lose that person for one reason or another.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_heart):

> A broken heart (also known as heartbreak or heartache) is a metaphor for the intense emotional stress or pain one feels at experiencing great loss or deep longing. The concept is cross-cultural, often cited with reference to unreciprocated or lost love.
>
> Failed romantic love can be extremely painful; people with a broken heart may succumb to depression, anxiety and, in more extreme cases, post-traumatic stress disorder.

From [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broken+heart):

> broken heart
> What one is said to have when they are very sad, typically due to a tragic event or the end of a romantic relationship.
> *When my girlfriend dumped me, I thought I would die from a broken heart.*
> *Well, my son is dead, and I feel like my broken heart will never heal—that's how I'm doing.*
> *Ah, you recently ended a relationship too. So there are two broken hearts here today, huh?*